# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str' - Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

| addition | add-revised |
| --- | --- |
| 6 insertions(+) | 6 |
| NaN | 0 |
| 8 insertions(+) | 8 |

From the 'addition' column of the data frame, I created the 'add-revised' column.

```
df['add-revised'] = df.addition.str.extract('(\d+)')
df['add-revised'] = df['add-revised'].fillna(0)
```

When I attempt to do

```
df_new['add-revised'].mean()
```

It's giving me the following error

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

I attempted to solve the problem with

```
df_new['add-revised'].to_numeric()
```

and it's giving me the following error

```
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'to_numeric'
```

Comment: Please post a fully running script so that others don't have to do that part in their answers. Its just an import and creating the dataframe.

Comment: I thnk you'd have gotten `NameError: name 'df_new' is not defined`. What is that variable? Anyway, `to_numeric` is a function. You could do `df['add-revised'] = pd.to_numeric(df['add-revised'])`. `atype` is a method, you could use that also.

Comment: ```df['add-revised'].astype(int).mean()``` perhaps this works. Also, we can't see any df_new, just df.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try:

```
df_new['add-revised'] = df_new['add-revised'].astype(int)
```

it works for pandas version '1.2.0'